# How to start developing for the Windows 7 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I had a link that had some great information regarding the new developer tools for Windows 7 phone, but I lost it! :(

Where can I download the appropriate tools? Is there an emulator that simulates the phone on my laptop so I can do short tech demos for my study group?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools you need are still in beta. You can get them from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3&displaylang=en . They work with whatever version of Visual Studio you have (Express right up to ultimate.) I just blogged some links to resources to help you get started: http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/SomeWindowsPhone7Resources.aspx.

Comment: Update: new versions available now at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49b9d0c5-6597-4313-912a-f0cca9c7d277

Answer (score 5):

everything you need is **FREE** and available here:

http://developer.windowsphone.com/Default.aspx

Basically it's Visual Studio Express for Windows phone and Expression Blend Express for Windows phone. There's a 3.5Mb bootstrapper that will download everythingh you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the latest Visual Studio.

You can get it for free if you're a student from [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com).

There's an [add-on](https://www.dreamspark.com/Products/Product.aspx?ProductId=28) for Windows 7 phone to get to the marketplace

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed; what do I need to download then?

Answer (score 0):

@Poleman 
The Beta version of Windows Phone 7 will install Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone and well as Expression Studio for Windows Phone too. These are free as well.