# In windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In windows phone 7 ,is there any combo box and table view control.
If any one knows tel , friends.

And how to web service in wiindows phone 7.how to bind those values into list box or table view control.

thanks & Regrads,
 selladurai

Comment: You posted a lot of questions together. Try asking them separately with proper post titles to get proper answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a combobox, as such, in WP7 but one of the AutoCompleteBox, ListPicker or LongListSelector (from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034)) may be appropriate, depending on your specific needs.

A table or grid view doesn't translate well to the "Metro" style and has usability issues on a small screen. As such, no equivalent control has been provided.

You can use any kind of web service on WP7 but proxy generation from WSDL services isn't directly supported. It's recommended to use a WCF/ODATA backend or a rest based service.

Data retrieved from a web service can be turned into objects and then bound to the UI using viewmodels.

You may want to take a look at the following questions which have already been asked:
[Want to start with Windows Phone 7 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191756/want-to-start-with-windows-phone-7-development)
[How to start developing for the Windows 7 phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489303/how-to-start-developing-for-the-windows-7-phone)
[Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)
[Resources for Windows Phone 7 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267229/resources-for-windows-phone-7-development)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318003/learning-to-develop-for-windows-phone-7

To get better (more specific) answers, please see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) on asking questions.